# Exception handling onException() using Apache Camel

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I am trying to handle Exception in my code. Below is the code:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

        onException(Exception.class).process(new Processor() {

                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("handling ex");
                    }
        }).log("Received body").handled(true).end();

        from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data.csv")
        .process(new MyTransformRevised1())
        .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=emp.xml")
        .split(body().tokenizeXML("equityFeeds", null)).streaming().to("jms:queue:xml.inbound.topic");
}
```

Now if suppose in the line: `from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data.csv")` if the file "data.csv" is not present in my resources folders then shouldn't it throw **FileNotFoundException** and go into the onException() handler and print "handling ex"? Also when this code runs my log statement is also not printed to the console.

Currently its not going into the onException() handler. I am failing to understand as to why? Please kindly help me solve this issue.

Comment: No, file consumer will wait to file to be present in folder. There will be no exception thrown.

Comment: @Bedla: strange I though it would give me FileNotFoundException and was trying to understand that why its not giving me exception.

Answer (score 0):

As @bedla already commented, you will **not get a FileNotFoundException** because `from("file:...") creates a file consumer that is **listening continuously for new files** in the directory you configure.

The **`filename` option acts as a filter**. That means your file consumer processes only files with the name `data.csv`.

So if you drop a file with this name, it will be consumed and moved to a subfolder (I think the default name is `.camel`). Then you can drop another `data.csv` into the folder and it will be consumed too. If you remove the `filename` option, it consumes every file you drop into the folder.

If you don't want to have a continuous file import from a folder, but want to **import a specific file as part of your processing workflow**, have a look at [Camel Poll Enrich EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html). There is a [simple example that imports a file](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html#_pollenrich_example).